# Should I use two "not" here in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

Should I use:

```
"This approach is not economic and user friendly blah blah ..."
```

Or

```
"This approach is not economic and not user friendly blah blah ..."
```

Or anything else?

Comment: Welcome to [english.se]. Questions should be researched before asking, and the research results should be added to the question. Thanks.

Comment: Research? You mean Google?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that only using one *not* can be ambiguous about user-friendliness. However, using *not* twice is awkward. You could consider the following, of which I think I prefer the second.

> This approach is not economic or user-friendly ...
>   This approach is neither economic nor user-friendly ...